# Neo4j Cypher or php finding "People you may know"

Tags: neo4j

Im new on Neo4j, for 4-5 days im looking for cypher and php (everyman's) codes but i couldnt understand how can i make a script like facebooks you may know ?

I create an index called places . And create 4 persons who :LIVES_ON that places.

[image: Sample of my neo4j graphic]
As you see, there 2 two person (their ids : 105,110) and 1 place(its id : 492)

Now thinking that , im 105 user and im on 492 place. How can i find 110  who lives also 492 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question is very basic, it might be helpful to first gain a understanding of the core concepts of Cypher, e.g. by going through the [free online training](http://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-course/).

Your verbal query description is: Give me all people who live on the same place as myself.

The `myself` is determined by a node id 105 as you've stated above - this is the filter condition.

The query looks like:

```
MATCH (me)-[:LIVES_ON]->(place)<-[:LIVES_ON]-(other)
WHERE ID(me) = 105
RETURN other
```

Comment: So thanks my man, yes question may be simple but as i said im new on it. But so thanks for your descriptive message.